# jQuery UI autocomplete after AJAX <select>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

im having a problem after i select one option

```
<select name="opcoes" onchange="showInfo(this.value)">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

I send a option value through this

```
function showInfo(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("fields").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("fields").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/php/search/getRow.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

That gives my getRow.php the ID to show from the Database a table with inputs so a person can change their values, now i have two fields that need jQuery-UI autocomplete so i have this javascript but its not working.

This is the generated code from the getRow.php

```
<input type="text" name="editname" id="namesearch" value="one">
<input type="text" name="editname" id="modelsearch" value="wfmq015">
```

This is my autocomplete...

```
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $("#namesearch").autocomplete({
        source: "/js/namer.php",
        minLength: 0
    });    

    $("#modelsearch").autocomplete({
        source: "/js/modeler.php",
        minLength: 1
    });              

});
```

I think my problem is that the javascript is notcatching the id's in time since it was an ajax request... can anyone help me out?

The Javascript's are placed in the main page that calls the ajax to get some more elements into it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes. Looks like you wrote your own AJAX call. Let's use jQuery for this instead. Save yourself some major headache

```
function showInfo(str) {
    $.get("/php/search/getRow.php?id=" + str, function(html) {
        $("#fields").html(html);
    });
}
```

Now, to your second question, the problem is you're using the AJAX to load your fields but are instantiating the autocomplete when the page is loaded. So I would put those into a function and add that to your AJAX callback

```
function loadAuto() {
    $("#namesearch").autocomplete({
        source: "/js/namer.php",
        minLength: 0
    });    

    $("#modelsearch").autocomplete({
        source: "/js/modeler.php",
        minLength: 1
    });
}
function showInfo(str) {
    $.get("/php/search/getRow.php?id=" + str, function(html) {
        $("#fields").html(html);
        loadAuto();
    });
}
```

Comment: Going for a smoke to get ready to implement this i will let you know in 10minutes thank you very much :D